# Spark Job takes a long time

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr

I am writing a spark/scala ETL job that does some data manipulation, data is read from mongo db and redshift, joined, mapped and then saved to s3. all transformations are done using spark api (select, UDF) using Dataframes and Datasets. 
Data is not very big, total amount of rows are about 1M and it's mostly select statements and udf. 
For some reason this job takes about an hour to run (EMR, 1 master and 11 cores 16cpu on each worker, 32GB ram each worker)

I have set dynamicLocation to true and I do see at all workers take on task, However when I write the data to s3 (final and only action) the program writes 200 files and they increase in size, the first are a few MB and the last once are around 30MB, final file is 100MB. since the number of files is the number of partitions of RDD and number of tasks, this makes me think that maybe task are not handling equal size of data and thus the parallelism is not working properly.

Can this be the case?

Thanks
Nir

Comment: This might be a partitioning issue. But, it will help more if you could share your code that you have written to save data in S3 via Spark.

Comment: It might also help if you ran this through a profiling tool and saw where the time is being taken.

Comment: @JoeC - have you used a profiling tool? can you share the name? thanks

Comment: I tend to use `jvisualvm`.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian. I use the spark save: entityDataFrameTrimmed.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(directory)

Comment: @NirBenYaacov You can use `entityDataFrameTrimmed.write.repartition("col").partitionBy("col").format("json").mode("overwrite"‌​).save(directory)` to save data. It is suppose to be faster.

Comment: Did you check spark gui where the time and resource are spent most

Comment: According to the spark GUI most of the time is spent on the last file (last task in the only action) @NomanKhan

Comment: You can  use custom partitionar as it  seems data is not evenly distibuted.